# "На любые фигуру и рост" или "на любую фигуру и рост"?

Tags: грамматика

Как правильно пишется: *на любые фигуру и рост* или *на любую фигуру и рост*?

Answer (score 3):

...на любую фигуру и рост

Определение, относящееся к двум или нескольким существительным – однородным членам, ставится в форме е д и н с т в е н н о г о числа:

1) если по смыслу сочетания ясно, что определение относится не только к ближайшему существительному, но и к последующим, например: российская печать, радио и телевидение; подъём нашей техники, науки и культуры; декада норвежской литературы и искусства; создание новой оперы, балета, музыкальной комедии; литературный карьеризм и индивидуализм; школьная успеваемость и дисциплина; в своём изложении и выводах…; каждый завод и фабрика; уличный шум и грохот; летний жар и зной; морской прилив и отлив; различной формы и цвета.
http://knowed.ru/index.php?id=884&name=pages&op=view